Can you log out of Ubuntu Pro remotely?
I have a free Ubuntu Pro subsccription, but I lost my computer with it. I have a new one and I logged in, but there is a machine it counts that I can't use, how do I log it out? I do not have anything installed on it.

Can you logout a machine from Ubuntu Pro? No.
But doing so is designed to be unnecessary.
From Machine counts and token usage for Ubuntu Pro:

Monitoring active machines
Active machines are counted based on the number of machines attached to your subscription at a given time. An active machine is defined as a machine that has been attached to a given subscription at any point within the past 24 hours.

A token is no longer considered active after 24 hours.
A personal account is not limited to 5 tokens. It's limited to 5 active systems. You can have more tokens.
Of course, if your "lost" computer is actually being used by somebody else and is truly active, then you have a bigger problem than Ubuntu Pro.
